# How come sometimes in calculus problem solving questions, the "C" which comes from integration can sometimes be assumed to be zero.

Tags: calculus

I'm just wondering why, at times, at time$=0$, the distance can be assumed to equal zero, meaning the C can become zero (the $C$ from integration). For example in this question:

A go-kart from a starting point moves at a velocity of $6$ metres per second in a straight line. It's acceleration is given by $a(t) = -2.5t^2$ after leaving the starting point.

So we can integrate it and get:

$$v = \frac{2.5}{3}t^3 + C$$

and eventually,

$$s = 2.5 t^3 + C$$

So how come, in the $s$ equation, the co-ordinates $(0,0)$ can be substituted in to get $C=0$? Isn't it moving at $6$ m/s at the starting point?

Thanks

Comment: You integrated twice. First to get $V$ then $S$ as a function of $t$. So you should have two integration constants $C_1$ and $C_2$. The value of one of them is determined by the initial speed, the value of the other by the initial location.

Comment: Your second integration is wrong and you need to check it. Also the sign of the acceleration is given as negative, but your velocity is increasing, so you need to check that as well. As to constants, you have two initial conditions - velocity and position, to determine constants for the two integrations you do.